# Get only the path from a function like previous_post_link

Tags: navigation

I want to use something like `previous_post_link('%link','',TRUE )` and put the path into a javascript variable.

So using something like

`var previous = "<?php previous_post_link(  '%link','',TRUE ); ?>";`

outputs :

`<a href="http://www.website.com/photo/1085" rel="prev"></a>`

but instead I only want the path output in that variable.

`http://www.website.com/photo/1085`

I like this function because it allows you to remain in category so I am hoping for a solution where I still can easily have that as an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following function in your functions.php file.

```
function custom_post_link($format, $link, $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = '', $previous = true) {
if ( $previous && is_attachment() )
    $post = & get_post($GLOBALS['post']->post_parent);
else
    $post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous);

if ( !$post )
    return;

$link = get_permalink($post);

$format = str_replace('%link', $link, $format);

$adjacent = $previous ? 'previous' : 'next';
echo apply_filters( "{$adjacent}_post_link", $format, $link );
}
```

and instead of calling previous_post_link('%link','',TRUE ) function call it as custom_post_link('%link','',TRUE ) and it will output the path as following

```
http://www.website.com/photo/1085
```

Comment: You are always welcome.