# customize urls displayed by previous_post_link and next_post_link

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, mod-rewrite, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I am using the below code to display my next and previous links in single.php:

```
<div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<img height="34" src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/previous.png" />' ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '<img height="34" src="' . get_bloginfo("template_directory") . '/images/next.png" />' ); ?></div>
```

Everything is working well except that I am defining some rewrite rules in my websites so I am not using the default links like:

```
http://local-host/enc/?aya-bi-aya=aya-143
```

but instead

```
http://local-host/enc/aya-bi-aya/aya-143/
```

I managed to change the structures of my links for all the website except for the next and previous links, since it requires maybe change of core code!!

How can I customize the urls returned by these two Wordpress functions?

Thanks for your time and consideration.

**Edit:**

I am using custom post type(=aya-bi-aya).My permalink structure is set to default. It then displays my permalinks like:

```
http://local-host/enc/?aya-bi-aya=aya-143
```

But inside my website, I dont need such urls, but instead I am using urls like:

```
http://local-host/enc/?aya-bi-aya=aya-143&assurah=al-baqarah&attab=attakhrij
```

The additional parameters fulfill  my needs, especially in my jquery code.
Plus, I am using the mod_rewrite to tranform my links to:

```
http://local-host/enc/aya-bi-aya/al-baqarah/aya-143/attakhrij/
```

The only remaining thing is to change the links in previous and next, so that they respect this last shape.

Thanks Milo for triggering the real issue.

Comment: This can help you. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46761/get-only-the-path-from-a-function-like-previous-post-link/46763

Comment: those functions ultimately use `get_permalink` to output the links, how are you outputting the correct links for single posts? are these a custom post type? if you correctly filter `post_link` or `post_type_link` to format your URLs, this problem will disappear, but I have a feeling you've gone about the whole thing in a strange way to end up where you are now.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces If you found any solution then add it here as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Milo: I am using the default permalink structure for my custom post type (aya-bi-aya) + other params that I am not including in my question, I am giving an edit. I am trying to understand the idea about `post_link` and `post_type_link`. thanks

Comment: @VinodDalvi of course. I am still reading your link and trying to understand Milo comment

Comment: @Milo, I hope I explained well.